# how use functional programming in scala function

Tags: scala

I am developing `translate` function in Scala. It consists to insert the "av" character, just before a vowel-like `'a' , 'e' , 'i', 'o' or 'u'`.
Note that text string has length restrictions. It should not has a length of more than 225 characters and if it's empty, it should return an empty string:
In another world:
if

```
text = "abdcrfehilmoyr"
```

the result should be : `"avabdcrfehavilmavoyr"`

So, I developed this function :

```
def translate(text: String): String = {
  var voyelle = Array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
  for (w <- (0,text.length())){
    if ((text.contains(voyelle[w]) == true)) {
      text.patch(w, "av", 0)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way, to use instead functional programming like map, flat map functions to simplify the code ?

Comment: This code doesn't compile as-is - the `for(w <- (0,text.length()))` doesn't work like this.

Comment: Yes, you can use `flatMap` that is all you asked, hope you can find the answer.

Comment: What do you want to optimize / simplify for? As it stands the question is rather option-based and unlikely to generate a definitive answer.

Comment: @k0pernikus, I am beginner in scala, thank you if you can give me complete answer

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, can you post your answer using `flatMap`, thanks

Comment: @k0pernikus Asking specific "how-to" questions is not on-topic for CodeReview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String is effectively a collection of `char`'s so you [can treat it like one](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/strings.html#inner-main). For example:

```scala
val result = text
  .map(c => if (voyelle.contains(c)) "av" + c else c.toString)
  .mkString
```

Comment: Hello @Guru Stron, thank you for the response, but, your code adds "av" after the vowel, I am looking to add "av" *before* the vowel and not *after* it.

Comment: @Imed there was small typo. [Try it out](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Oo4iUNSmTdGkBAtvYThgnA).

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
   text.replaceAll("([aeiou])", "av$1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `flatMap`

```scala
def translate(text: String): String = {
  val vowels = Set('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
  text.trim.toLowerCase.flatMap { c =>
    if (vowels.contains(c)) s"av${c}"
    else c.toString
  }
}
```

*code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/jfMIG5IVTYaz51EsK1L8Qw/1)*.